# Creating a 2D map

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a table of coordinates and value for each coordinate. Something like shown in the picture:

[Data format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGPCp.png)

How can i make a map out of this data( i need a two dimensional represenation with every coordinate represented as a rectangle and the value written inside - something like shown in this pic below
[How i want results to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJe2w.png)

I tried to use meshgrid- but did not help. Any help would be appreciated

```
plt.figure(figsize=(15,15))
path=r'C:\GF\three_3Deep\Scripts\Data\21ACI_Massive_Prec_Result\results_run5.csv'
data=pd.read_csv(path)
#u = np.arange(-2, 2)
u=data.FX
#v = np.arange(-1, 5)
v=data.FY
X,Y = np.meshgrid(u, v)

#Z = X**2/25 + Y**2/4
size_of_mesh=(len(X),len(X))
z=np.zeros(size_of_mesh)
z1 = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Slant1_Avg.euclidean'])
np.fill_diagonal(z, z1)

print('z:\n', Z)
#plt.set_cmap('gray')
plt.pcolor(z)
plt.show()
```

Comment: [does this help?](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/image_annotated_heatmap.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you just want to transform your data into a 2D-array to plot as a heatmap. I assume you have no repeat points. You can use pandas to easily pivot your data into a 2D array:

```
import pandas as pd

# Create sample data
np.random.seed(42)
pts = np.random.choice(np.arange(20*20), size=30, replace=False)
X, Y = np.unravel_index(pts, (20, 20))
Z = np.random.random(size=30) * 50
df = pd.DataFrame(np.column_stack([X, Y, Z]), columns=list('XYZ'))

# Reshape data
df = df.pivot(index='Y', columns='X', values='Z')
```

Seaborn has a `heatmap` function to annotate your map. Depending on whether you want your rectangles to fill to the next point or be unit squares (1x1), you can do one of the following methods:

```
sns.heatmap(df, annot=True)
```

[image]

OR

```
sns.heatmap(df.reindex(index=np.arange(20), columns=np.arange(20)), annot=True)
```

[image]